# DotVVM 2.0 - unable to run trial Business Pack controls

Tags: dotvvm

I’ve created a DotVVM Core 2.0 project using Visual Studio and I have activated a trial version of Business Pack that I have added into that project from the private feed. I have registered the Business Pack in DotvvmStartup.cs in ConfigureServices. I don’t see bp controls in IntelliSense and when I try to run web app with the bp controls I get an error that tagprefix was not registered.

I use latest version of Visual Studio 2017 Community and latest versions of DotVVM and Business Pack. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Perhaps you won't call method `DotvvmStartup.ConfigureServices`. It is cause by "bug" in VS2017 extension template (v2.0.118.0 and below) and dotnet CLI template (dotvvm.templates.2.0.3).

Please check `Startup.ConfigureServices`.

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
      ...
      services.AddDotVVM(); //this line is incorrect
  }
```

You should replace `services.AddDotVVM()` with `services.AddDotVVM<DotvvmStartup>();` 
https://github.com/riganti/dotvvm/blob/master/src/DotVVM.Framework.Hosting.AspNetCore/ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L17

This create instance of `DotvvmStartup` and call method `DotvvmStartup.ConfigureServices`.
DotvvmStartup object is created 2 times (`services.AddDotVVM<DotvvmStartup>()` and `app.UseDotVVM<DotvvmStartup>(env.ContentRootPath)`).